# Tools for drawing/converting SVG drawing in HTML5 canvas element drawing

Tags: html, canvas, svg

I just have moved from SVG to HTML canvas in HTML5.
I have made seven design using various tools and software in SVG drawing.
I just wanted to know Is there a similar tool for drawing as used in SVG.
Example . I used inkscape for drawing in SVG is there similar product for HTML canvas drawing.

```
        Or a way to convert my Drawing From SVG TO HTML5 canvas.
```

Comment: You know there is an SVG tag in HTML5, ie, you don't have to convert necessarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't (disclaimer: to my knowledge) any package/library/tool which works as Inkscape built on Canvas.

There exists many libraries though which makes it easier to create objects and drawings on canvas, but all are for API usage - ie. you must program it your self eventually create your own UX on top to provide similar functionality such as Inkscape etc.

Library recommendations are however off-topic for SO.